# Why mocha instead of QA

Tags: mocha.js

I just found out about Mocha, so please excuse the question if the answer is obvious.

I can't figure out why use Mocha.js, if by the time I write a test procedure I can manually do the test myself.

All of the examples I see online present trivial tasks for tests like

```
"should return a string when it gets a number".
```

Ok, how about I just go to my browser, punch in a number and see if I get a string?

Basically, I'm just struggling to see how Mocha (or any other testing framework for that matter) can help me debug and test my app.

Thank you all for explaining this to me. I am certain who ever developed mocha did it for a very good reason, I just need some help figuring out what this reason is.

**A little clarification:**
Every function I run on my website includes a test. When I get a query string I check if it's valid before running it against my database.

Whenever I pull information out of my db I check if my db returned errors, and so on.

What am I missing?

Comment: Autotesting isn't QA replacement,but the developer's best friend in revealing regressions and bugs right after code modifications. If most of default use cases of your application will be covered with auto tests, then developer will be aware of new bugs immediately and will be able to fix them asap.

Comment: Could you give a simple real world example?

Comment: It was too long for comment. Check the answer pls

Answer (score 0):

For example, you have a library Web app dealing with books, people, so on. And your library owner asks you to implement new feature,for example,for buying books out of library permanently. You have analyzed this feature and started your coding. And with code modifications you had to change old, really old parts of code base strongly,used by a lot of modules of your application. And if you have autotests for your application you can just write any of modifications and running autotests constantly to proof  you are on the right way, and to catch any new bugs you caused,and you will call QA only in the finish of your coding to check the full solution once. And if you don't have autotests, you have to waste time waiting for QA to pass tests manually after any of code modifications.